# How to find the physical directory of an application on IIS with NSIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, nsis

I'm building an installer with NSIS that will install multiple ASP.NET applications at the same time. I only need to find the physical directory of these applications on the server to install my files.

NsisIIS provides functions to return: web sites, virtual directory and app pools, but nothing to return a list of applications and their properties.

I already know the name of these applications, but the physical directories varies from server to server.

I was wondering if someone had a solution to this problem.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can use the APPCMD.exe, which can do the job for you. Just call it from NSIS like this:

```
Section "Test"
    nsExec::ExecToStack 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list vdir "Default Web Site/virtual_path" /text:physicalpath'
    Pop $0 ;return value
    Pop $1 ;printed text
    DetailPrint "output from command: $1"
SectionEnd
```

You must after all call Pop twice, because ExecToStack stores the return value (%errorlevel%) above the text returned from executed command.